# How to execute a code that doesn't stop the rest if broken with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a full system with both Laravel and VueJS and at some point, I'm generating pictures from a list of pictures with Image Intervention.

But this process can break, there are many issues that I faced and resolved that can appear in the future.

**What would you recommend me to do to have a broken code not stop the rest ?** I was thinking on some service that would be called and be independent, asynchronous.

Can Laravel cover that ? I have read about events in both Laravel and Symfony but that is something I never understood.

Greetgins

Comment: Sure. You could use queued jobs, try/catch, do the image rendering via an entirely separate app... there are various options available to you.

Comment: Queue/Jobs is what you need as @ceejayoz said, here are the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues)

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the english vocabulary to find this. I will dive into it and keep the post updated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was in a similar problem some days ago. Although, My problem was related to inserting data from CSV to the database. So, there were chances of having some different datatype that might generate the error and halt the whole remaining process. So, I used try catch inside my job. I will show you reference, you can modify as you wish:

```
$error_arr = array();
$error_row_numbers = array();

try{
         //Write your code here that might throw error
        $row = Model::updateOrCreate(
            ['id' => $id,
            $Arr
        );

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       //Optionally you can store error message
       //and image number which is failed here
         $error_arr[] = $e->getMessage();
         $error_row_numbers[] = $row_no; //this row_no is different variable
                                         //and should be increased in loop
                                         //to determine exact image

    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ! How is using an exception different than testing a variable and having a Else condition ? What should I do with exceptions ? Log ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. But, as far as I understand your question, I want  to say that if else is different than exception handling. In if else, it will halt the whole process if it encounters an error. However, you can use if else if an error can arise, if it could don't even start the execution. This example can be something like: `field_1` need to be an integer, in this case, you can say `if(field_1 is an integer){execute insert function} else{ just skip }`. But, its better and mostly all task with the possible error are run inside `try{} catch()`

Comment: You understood my question perfectly. You're telling me that I can handle errors in PHP without stopping the whole script ? Because in production, let's say the function to generate a preview image doesn't work or is slowed down by the API, I wouldn't want to stop the process, the preview image isn't more important than the rest of the script. Can I use exceptions to create a log line in my log file, and keep going ? That way I could put exceptions everywhere to control my code in production. Thank you again, you got me curious !

Comment: @Mr.Miel Why don't use laravel mail function instead. I have shown you the way to store error message and some unique identity of items. You can store image name / id to determine which is failed. And. later send those array of data to mail to the user who started that image generation function. So, that he can again start those failed image.